# Samba: How do I set passwords for the users in the username map?

Tags: samba

I want to map a large number of login usernames to a few unix users, so I guessed the [username map](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#USERNAMEMAP) config option is an appropriate way.

I enabled it for a particular share in smb.conf:

```
security = share
[some_share]
username_map = /etc/samba/some_share.map
```

and added all the usernames to the map:

```
some_share_user = anton berta caesar ...
```

But how do I set the passwords for those users?

```
# smbpasswd -a anton
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user anton.
```

Though it doesn't say so explicitly, I guess this is because smbpasswd checks if there is a matching unix user and forgets to check all the username maps, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you linked to explicitly states

> Please note that for user or share mode security, the username map is applied prior to validating the user credentials.

This means that you will have to set a shared password for `some_share_user` and make anton, berta, and caesar log in with that password.

It works exactly the opposite way if anton, berta, and caesar are users in a Windows domain. They will use their domain credentials to log in to your samba server. Then samba will map them to `some_share_user`.

Comment: In other words, it is not possible to have one common UNIX user but different passwords for different users.

Comment: But with `security = share` deprecated, how do we achieve this objective?